# Selecting a div with same ID as the rel attribute of clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

This is a two-part question. I'm using jQuery for a project and wanting to click a link and toggle the class name "highlight" to that link and also to the div with the same id as the *rel* attribute of the link. I then want to be able to link to the next div without the classname of "highlight". Here's the HTML for it:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#" rel="panel1">Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" rel="panel2">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#" rel="panel3">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>  

<a href="">go to next div without class of highlight</a>


<div id="panel1">some text</div>
<div id="panel2">some text</div>
<div id="panel3">some text</div>
```

Can anyone help with jQuery side of things?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming HTML like this:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" rel="panel1">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="panel2">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="panel3">Item 3</a></li>
</ul>

<a id="next-unhighlighted">Go to next div without class "highlight"</a>

<div class="panel" id="panel1">Panel 1</div> <!-- Note the added -->
<div class="panel" id="panel2">Panel 2</div> <!-- "panel" classes -->
<div class="panel" id="panel3">Panel 3</div>
```

You can use JS like this:

```
$('ul li a').click(function () {
  var $this = $(this), // <a>
      id = $this.attr('rel'),
      nextUnhighlighted = $('#next-unhighlighted'), // <a>
      targetDiv = $('#' + id),
      nextDiv;

  // Un/highlight the clicked link
  $this.toggleClass('highlight');

  // Un/highlight the div related to the target link
  targetDiv.toggleClass('highlight');

  // Update nextUnhighlighted to point to next unhighlighted div
  nextDiv = $('div.panel:not(.highlight)');
  if (nextDiv[0]) { // A next sibling was found
    nextUnhighlighted.attr('href', '#' + nextDiv.attr('id'));
  } else {
    nextUnhighlighted.removeAttr('href');
  }
});
```

​
Note that, if the final panel is already highlighted, then this code does *not* update the `href` attribute for `a#next-unhighlighted`, but removes it. It's a trivial exercise to add wrap-around behavior, such that highlighting the final panel would link back to the first panel.

A note about the odd syntax `if (nextDiv[0])`: If the first element in the jQuery collection `nextDiv` exists, then there is at least one element in the collection. This behaves similarly to (but not exactly the same as) `nextDiv.length > 0`, but is marginally faster and smaller.

---

As discussed in the comments, to link each panel to the next unhighlighted one, add `<a rel="next-panel">Next panel</a>` to each panel's HTML, then add something like this to the main click handler:

```
$('div.panel a[rel="next-panel"]').each(function () {
  var $this = $(this),
      nextPanel = $this.parent().next('div.panel:not(.highlight)');
  if (nextPanel[0]) {
    $this.attr('href', '#' + nextPanel.attr('id'));
  }
});
```

Depending on your project requirements, you'll need to initialize each of these `next-panel` links (or else they'll only initialize after the first click), and you may want to make the final panel's ;oml wrap around to the first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that - it works up to a point although if I click item 2, the link goes to #panel3 when it should go to #panel1 (which is the next div without .highlight). I also want to be able to "highlight" multiple links, so that clicking on Item 1 and Item 2 will link to #panel3.

Comment: I also need to be able to toggle the classes so clicking Item 1 will add .highlight and clicking it again would remove it.

Comment: Updated; I had understood "next div without .highlight" to mean the next div after the currently highlighted one. The latest code now links to the *first* unhighlighted div.

Comment: You're bloody awesome - I'll give that a go :)

Comment: A thousand thanks Ron - that works like a charm! Just to complicate matters a bit further, do you know how I would go about adding links to the text in each of the panels that would link to the next div in the sequence without the class of highlight?

Comment: I've updated my answer to cover linking from one panel to the next. It's not perfect, but you should be able to massage it to fit your project's evolving requirements.

Comment: Hey Ron, I've given this a go but still doesn't seem to be working. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: There's nothing different here between HTML 4 and HTML5, so it should be safe to assume it would work. A year late to answer the last commenter but probably worth noting anyway.